# Vagrant com PHP + MySQL + Linux + Puphpet + ZF2 muito lento

Tags: php, mysql, linux, vagrant

Tenho um ambiente montado no Windows com ZF2, Doctrine e MySQL que roda bem rápido.

Porém agora estou experimentando o Vagrant com a máquina configurada através do Puphpet. Consegui fazer o sistema funcionar nesse ambiente, porém ele está extremamente lento. E quando eu faço as buscas diretamente no MySQL pelo console, é super rápido. Não fiz alterações de configuração nem no PHP e nem no MySQL.

Teriam alguma luz para me dar?

Comment: Cara eu tentei usar o Puphpet(5vzs) e não consegui fazer funcionar o nginx e algumas outras coisas,o sistema deles é extremamente rápido mas acredito que não seja perfeitamente estável.
Eu excluí a VM e criei uma nova do zero sem puphet,te aconselho a fazer o mesmo. Abs

Answer (score 2):

O Vagrant reconhecidamente possui alguns problemas com desempenho, sendo o mais comum relacionado à sincronização de arquivos.

A [documentação do Vagrant](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html) fornece alternativas para sanar o problema usando NFS. ísso só funciona em linux. Se sua máquina *host* for Windows, pode usar [sincronização via SMB](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/smb.html).

Outros pontos em potencial que podem ser causa de lentidão são:

- Pouca memória disponível
- Poucos núcleos (*cores*) para processamento
- Problema com o *provider* padrão da VM (Virtual Box)